# jquery and google table visualization

Tags: jquery, visualization

I am hoping that there is someone that can help me. I am using the google.code visualization tools and jquery on the same page.

I am calling the `$(document).ready` function on the document but suspect the problem lies with calling the `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);` function.

Which still loads after the `document.ready` function and then does not apply the lightbox effect onto the table

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto1({theme:'facebook'});
    });
    </script>
```

Any ideas on how to apply the lightbox effect to a link in the table, after the google visualization table has loaded?

I have also added the complete script as I have it now should this help in finding the problem.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
      // Create and populate the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'No');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Page URL');
      data.addColumn('string', 'EDIT');
      data.addRows(10);
      <% while ((Repeat1__numRows-- != 0) && (!rs_page_1.EOF)) { %>
      data.setCell(<%= Repeat1__index %>, 0, '<%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_page_no").Value)%>');
      data.setCell(<%= Repeat1__index %>, 1, '<a href="<%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_page_site").Value)%><%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_page_url").Value)%>"><%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_page_site").Value)%><%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_page_url").Value)%></a>');
      data.setCell(<%= Repeat1__index %>, 2, '<span class="gallery clearfix"><div class="btn_newsite"><a href="/application/functions/preview.asp?g_sites_no=<%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_sites_no").Value)%>&amp;g_page_no=<%=(rs_page_1.Fields.Item("g_page_no").Value)%>&amp;iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto1[iframes]" title="View">Edit</a></div></span>');
      <%
  Repeat1__index++;
  rs_page_1.MoveNext();
};
%>
      // Create and draw the visualization.
      visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
      visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': 'true'}, {'showRowNumber': 'true'}, {'firstRowNumber': '1'});
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
<div id="table"></div><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto1({theme:'facebook'});
        });
        </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit for this specific Google Visualization API:*

The `.draw()` method isn't immediate, it still has some work to do and it doesn't do it in the current thread (since it may need to retrieve an image from a server, etc).  They offer an event listener though, you can use it to listen for the [`ready` event](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/events.html#The_Ready_Event), like this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(visualization, 'ready', function() {
  $(".gallery a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto1({theme:'facebook'});
});
```

Add this code **between** these two lines so it's sure to fire:

```
visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': 'true'}, {'showRowNumber': 'true'}, {'firstRowNumber': '1'});
```

This will ensure the `.prettyPhoto1()` runs after all the elements are loaded and ready to go, including the ones in the visualization.  Still leave out the `document.ready` in this case, only run the plugin once.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for the answer, it however is still not working. could it be that I have a repeat column? and the function is needed for each time I need the lightbox? I have the lightbox on two other buttons, which do load (but which are not part of the repeat?). but the once in the repeat is not working... (because it only gets called once?)

Comment: @Gerald - You're saying the `rel="prettyPhoto1[iframes]"` are the only ones not working correctly?

Comment: Yes, The (buttons with rel="prettyPhoto1[iframes]" outside the google visualizations works 100%) but the ones within the google visualization is not working. (it opens a new page, instead of opening the lightbox?) - The google visualization table is loading, and does show the buttons with the rel="prettyPhoto1[iframes]" but it is not loading the lightbox if I click on it.

Comment: @Gerald - Their plugin model's a bit different, I assumed that the table would just render in the current thread, but that's not the case...try the updated answer, again leave out the `document.ready` just use the above.